# Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

My App worked fine the last couple of days, but suddenly I get this error.

I already tried these things:

- Restart Xcode & mac
- Clean Projects
- Clean Derived Data Folder

Here is the error:

```
ld /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleappTests.xctest/sampleappTests normal x86_64
    cd /Users/someuser/Development/Workspaces/2015/ios/myapp
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Intermediates/sampleapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleappTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sampleappTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -bundle_loader /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Intermediates/sampleapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleappTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sampleappTests.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Intermediates/sampleapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleappTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/sampleappTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleappTests.xctest/sampleappTests

ld: file not found: /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dohndrkqlwlrkeggboazluaanniz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Linker flags]

And here is one more warning

```
ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions: /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dsaagxaaoxqxgxcwdhubkhreboeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

Comment: Could you restore previous "fine" state from the VCS and prove that it still links successfully?

Comment: Did you rename the project?  Looks like it's target is set to "myapp" while he can't find it.

Comment: I just restored from the VCS. But I still get the error :-( This version worked yesterday!

Comment: Try: Application's target -> Build Settings -> Packaging options : rename the product to myapp

Comment: @PeterLenvay: It's already like that

Comment: Did you try to reset the simulator?

Comment: Are your test files named myappTests?

Comment: Yes. All names are okay.

Comment: If I compile the Watchkit App. I don't get the error.

Comment: What does the build log say when it links your main app rather than the test bundle?

Comment: Maybe there is the problem. I never told xCode to build the test-bundle.

Comment: Did you use Xcode beta before? Maybe error happens after you change to different Xcode version?

Comment: I am using the same Xcode beta (and re-installed this version already).  This is really strange.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of linker flags and another "warning". Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Checkbox for the Test-Targets fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: Where to find this (the image posted)?

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem with Cocoapods during unit testing, you can just add pods to your testing target and run `pod update` in the terminal. Here comes my example and it solves the problem:

```
target 'YourProject' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for YourProject
    pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController', '~> 2.0.13'
    pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 7.0'
    pod 'ZFRippleButton'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
    pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'
    pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.3'
    pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
    pod 'PKHUD', '~> 4.0'

    target 'YourProjectTests' do
        # inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
        pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController', '~> 2.0.13'
        pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 7.0'
        pod 'ZFRippleButton'
        pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
        pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 4.0.0'
        pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.3'
        pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
        pod 'PKHUD', '~> 4.0'
    end

    target 'YourProjectUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

end
```

After adding pods above, run `pod update`.